# Async call inside a cluster.on exit

Tags: node.js

I have a function like below but i am not sure if cluster.on exit behaves like process.on exit.

Is It correct or even possible to call an async function inside  the exit listener?

```
cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
  console.log(`${getCurrentTimestamp()} - worker ${worker.process.pid} died with code ${code}`);
  setTimeout(function({cluster.fork();}, 100);
})
```

Comment: I think it should work just fine.

Comment: You can call an asynchronous operation, but the process of exiting won't wait for your synchronous operation to complete before exiting.